# Using RDS as datasource for AWS Amplify Gen2

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-amplify, aws-rds-data-service

I'm currently looking into AWS Amplify Gen2, which looks really promising with using CDK, typescript schema bind etc

I know it's still in beta and under development, but I would like to test using a RDS (DataApi?) datasource instead of the default DynamoDB offering

Found this in one of the def files, but cant find any reference on how to use it yet
https://www.runpkg.com/?@aws-amplify/data-schema@0.13.16/lib-esm/src/ModelSchema.d.ts#99

Anyone got any pointers at this point?